# How can I add padding to my chart?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-toolkit

As you can see from below my LineSeries chart (Silverlight Toolkit) utilize the whole area. How can I add a padding to it? So that the line does not stop/end/start at the border. For as you can see from the label it gets overlapped with the border, making it look less nice.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you increase the axis? Like: Vertical axis goes from 1000 to 9000 - and horizontal axis goes from 30.07 up to 08.08.

And: If you want to set margins to the whole control - doesn't margins / padding work for you?